# Link to an ID on an external .php site

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, anchor, external

I'm having issues linking to an id(anchor) place on my index.php site from overview.php which are both in the same folder

This is the attributes on the div I want to link to (it is included in index.php using php include):
`<div id="landing" data-ancor="landing" name="landing">`

The code for the nav link I'm using is: 
`<li><a href="index.php#landing" data-taget="#landing">Forside</a></li>`

So the issue is that when I am on my `overview.php` i can't get to `index.php#landing`

The nav is also included using php include.

I hope you can help, please ask if anything is unclear or you need more information.
Best regards, Kasper

Comment: You can only anchor to an `<a />` tag, not a div (unless you are capturing the hash and doing some js to manually place focus on a div. I'm assuming you are being redirected to index.php#landing, but your div is not receiving/scrolling to focus?

Comment: If I understand correctly: you think that the link gets me to the index.php, but not to my div?
If its true, its unfortunately not the case. When I click the URL don't change so the URL is still overview.php

Comment: When you say the URL doesnt change, do you mean that the page does reload or the link doesn't do anything?. Also, I'm not sure if this makes a difference but target and anchor are both spelled incorrectly in your a tag and div tag as attributes.